# Simple MVC 3 No Submit Button

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-submit

I'm working my way through Pro ASP.NET MVC 3 by Steven Sanderson (yes, I know it's outdated). The first example, PartyInvites, is a simple MVC app that asks for name, email, and will attend. I typed in the code in VS 2010, and as far as my eyes can tell, everything is correct. Nevertheless, I don't have a Submit button. I've tried both Firefox and Explorer.

I know this isn't much info, but does anything jump right up to those in the know?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

My View Markup

```
<body>
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
<p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)</p>
<p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p> 
<p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)</p> 
<p>Will you attend? @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend, new[]{ new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes, I'll be there", Value = bool.TrueString}, new SelectListItem() {Text = "No, I can't come", Value = bool.FalseString} },"Coose an option" ) </p>
 } 
</body>
```

Comment: Perhaps you can post your View markup?

Comment: The book sample seems to have some actionlinks that you don't have, as  in `@Html.ActionLink("RSVP Now", "RsvpForm")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add an submit input to the form in order to render out a submit button.  I have not read the book in question, but he may have accidentally skipped that.  Be sure that the `<input type="submit"../>` is located within the `{}` of the `@Using(Html.BeginForm()`

```
<body>
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
<p>Your name: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Name)</p>
<p>Your email: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email)</p> 
<p>Your phone: @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Phone)</p> 
<p>Will you attend? @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.WillAttend, new[]{ new SelectListItem() {Text = "Yes, I'll be there", Value = bool.TrueString}, new SelectListItem() {Text = "No, I can't come", Value = bool.FalseString} },"Coose an option" ) </p>
<p><input type="submit" value="Save"/></p>
 } 
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.. you don't have a submit button.

I have the book somewhere.. I just can't find it at the moment. I wouldn't have thought there was a such a blindingly obvious error like this.

Anyway, pop this before the closing curly brace:

```
<input type="submit" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The book sample seems to have some actionlinks that you don't have, as in

```
@Html.ActionLink("RSVP Now", "RsvpForm")
```